# Saving changes to user profile changes Structure Listing URL

Tags: add-on, ee3, structure, zoo-visitor

We have an EE site running Visitor and Structure for our intra-net.  It's set up so that members can edit their profile on the "front end" without logging into the EE dashboard.  However, when someone edits their profile and saves, it resets their Structure Listing Url to "/" and thusly changes the home page for everyone else viewing the intranet.  Any ideas on where I could start digging to figure this one out?

- EE 3.5.15
- Wiki 3.0.2
- Structure 4.3.8
- Visitor 3.0.1
- Forms 4.0.0
- Low Events 2.0.1
- Polls 2.0
- SEO Lite 1.5.4
- Wygwam 4.1.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much digging I have added the following line to my visitor profile form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="structure_uri" value="{structure:page_slug_for:{entry_id}}" />
```

And this updates my structure listing url to be the appropriate url and not just a "/" upon save.